# ЗАЧЕМ нужны декораторы? (НЕ как они работают, а ЗАЧЕМ)

Tags: python, декоратор

Зачем нужны декораторы?

Кто читал классическое объяснение про декораторы:

```
# Декоратор - это функция, ожидающая ДРУГУЮ функцию в качестве параметра
def my_shiny_new_decorator(a_function_to_decorate):
    # Внутри себя декоратор определяет функцию-"обёртку".
    # Она будет (что бы вы думали?..) обёрнута вокруг декорируемой,
    # получая возможность исполнять произвольный код до и после неё.

    def the_wrapper_around_the_original_function():
        # Поместим здесь код, который мы хотим запускать ДО вызова
        # оригинальной функции
        print "Я - код, который отработает до вызова функции"

        # ВЫЗОВЕМ саму декорируемую функцию
        a_function_to_decorate()

        # А здесь поместим код, который мы хотим запускать ПОСЛЕ вызова
        # оригинальной функции
        print "А я - код, срабатывающий после"

    # На данный момент функция "a_function_to_decorate" НЕ ВЫЗЫВАЛАСЬ НИ РАЗУ

    # Теперь, вернём функцию-обёртку, которая содержит в себе
    # декорируемую функцию, и код, который необходимо выполнить до и после.
    # Всё просто!
    return the_wrapper_around_the_original_function

# Представим теперь, что у нас есть функция, которую мы не планируем больше трогать.
def a_stand_alone_function():
    print "Я простая одинокая функция, ты ведь не посмеешь меня изменять?.."

a_stand_alone_function()
# выведет: Я простая одинокая функция, ты ведь не посмеешь меня изменять?..

# Однако, чтобы изменить её поведение, мы можем декорировать её, то есть
# Просто передать декоратору, который обернет исходную функцию в любой код,
# который нам потребуется, и вернёт новую, готовую к использованию функцию:

a_stand_alone_function_decorated = my_shiny_new_decorator(a_stand_alone_function)
a_stand_alone_function_decorated()
#выведет:
# Я - код, который отработает до вызова функции
# Я простая одинокая функция, ты ведь не посмеешь меня изменять?..
# А я - код, срабатывающий после
```

Далее идет пассаж:

> Наверное, теперь мы бы хотели, чтобы каждый раз, во время вызова
>   a_stand_alone_function, вместо неё вызывалась
>   a_stand_alone_function_decorated. Нет ничего проще, просто перезапишем
>   a_stand_alone_function функцией, которую нам вернул
>   my_shiny_new_decorator:

```
a_stand_alone_function = my_shiny_new_decorator(a_stand_alone_function)
a_stand_alone_function()
#выведет:
# Я - код, который отработает до вызова функции
# Я простая одинокая функция, ты ведь не посмеешь меня изменять?..
# А я - код, срабатывающий после
```

Т.е. после этого пассажа - мы теряем возможность вызвать функцию в первоначальном виде. Теперь она ВСЕГДА декорирована.

И вопрос, зачем тогда декоратор был нужен?

1) Почему бы (если мы все равно теряем первоначальную функцию) просто не переписать изначальную функцию? (просто дописав в начале и в конце функции необходимые нам куски кода). Вот так:

```
def a_stand_alone_function():
    print "Я - код, который отработает до вызова функции"
    print "Я простая одинокая функция, ты ведь не посмеешь меня изменять?.."
    print "А я - код, срабатывающий после"
```

или, если дополнительный код большой и должен лежать отдельно, то:

```
def a_stand_alone_function():
        pre_function()
        print "Я простая одинокая функция, ты ведь не посмеешь меня изменять?.."
        post_function()
```

2) Зачем вся эта свистопляска, вместо того, чтобы сделать простое решение, как в 1 вопросе?

3) Я бы еще понял декораторы, если бы была возможность вызывать как декорируемую, так и изначальную функцию. Но декораторы, написанные с @ этого не позволяют. Зачем декоратор затирает оригинальную функцию?

Буду очень благодарен за ответ с объяснениями и, может быть, ПОНЯТНЫМИ примерами из реальной практики.

Comment: Ну первое, что приходит в голову, вы наследуетесь от чужого кода, который вы не перепишите.

Comment: Почему? Если он защищен авторским правом, то вы его и в декораторе не имеете права использовать. А если не защищен, то возьмем и перепишем. Я не понял, почему "чужеродность" кода оправдывает существование декораторов.

Comment: @UserNew `А если не защищен, то возьмем и перепишем` - у вас есть `dll` библиотеки. как вы её собираетесь переписать? Особенно не зная что там и где? А если там десятки тысяч строк и сотни классов внутри?  А если она будет обновляться? каждый раз переписывать?

Comment: @UserNew правильный вопрос не почему, а зачем. Зачем переписывать то, что уже написали? А тем более зачем переписывать это много раз?

Comment: @UserNew, в данном случае авторское право ни при чём.

Comment: Я примерно понимаю вашу мысль. Но если чужой код настолько запрятан, что мы даже не можем его ctrl-с - ctrl-v, то как можно его использовать вообще? Это ж черный ящик с практически непредсказуемым поведением? Т.е. как можно использоывать чужой код, не имея возможности просмотреть его?

Comment: @UserNew странный вопрос. Большинство библиотечного кода именно так и используется. Есть публичный интерфейс, есть документация его описывающая и нет никакой возможности узнать о реализации. Далеко за примерами ходить не надо, тот же WinAPI.

Comment: О WinAPI я не думал. Я пока что мыслю только в пределах python программ. И об импорте и декорировании python  модулей и python классов.(мне пока что попадались исключительно открытые. т.е. при желании я могу заглянуть в любой python пакет, который я установил и которым пользуюсь.) В том случае, если декорируемая функция написана на другом языке, или вообще написана неизвестно на чем и упрятана в какой-то контейнер - возможно, декорирование, единственный способ дополнить её, не погружаясь в непонятные дебри. - Да, понятно. Хороший пример. Спасибо.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Например, в Django декораторы широко используются. Вместо того, чтобы изобретать велосипед и в каждой функции-контроллере, которая должна быть доступна только авторизованным пользователям, писать свой код проверки авторизации, просто декорируем её, соответствующим декоратором. А если нужно ещё гарантировать, что функция будет применяться только для запросов определённого типа? И что вся работа с БД в функции будет выполняться в транзакции? Если весь код тянуть в функцию, то вскоре её изначальный смысл просто потеряется в куче шаблонного кода. А она ведь ещё и не одна в модуле, и для каждой придётся написать этот шаблонный код, повторив его множество раз. Вместо того, чтобы просто написать:

```
@require_POST
@login_required
@transaction_atomic
def some_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: Т.е вы имеете в виду, что можно один раз написать декоратор и использоывать его на куче функций, если он там повторяется? Например, в html странице - отрисовку верхнего логотипа, бокового меню и нижней заметки об авторских правах - сделать декоратором. И лепить этот декоратор на генерацию ВСЕХ страниц сайта, больше не заботясь об этих 3 элементах. Я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Да, одна из причин использования декораторов - это возможность не повторяться. Это форма структурирования кода, такая же как само использование функций. Ведь можно же и функции не вызывать, а просто вставлять их код в места, где он нужен.

Comment: @UserNew вы путаете, для отрисовки обычно используются шаблоны,  допустим декотратор позволит поставить права на все функции которые допустим доступны только администрации (а их бывает много)   и нет необходимости в дублировании кода

Comment: Я думаю, что понял этот пример. У меня в голове была мысль, что декорируемая функция - это нечто главное, а декораторы - это просто украшалки (ну, название то, к этому располагает). И я возмущался: какого фига после украшательства, мы теряем возможность изсползовать это главное само по себе, без декораторов (украшательств). А получается, что это деление неправильное. Это просто элементы одного целого. А декораторы - это то, что может понадобиться не в одном месте, а в нескольких. Тогда имеет смысл их применять.

Comment: Правильно? Тогда пример с однйо единственной декорируемой функцией - ущербен, ибо не доносит эту мысль и никак не неё не намекает. Т.е. декоратор для одной функции - это бессмысленность. Так? Или есть примеры, когда декоратор может быть и не повторяющимся в разных местах элементом?

Comment: Вполне имеет смысл и одну функцию декорировать. Взять хотя бы мой пример, зачем мне переписывать механизм управления транзакциями, если я могу просто написать перед функцией `@transaction_atomic`? Это и быстрее и правильнее в архитектурном плане, так как код функции и код управления транзакциями хоть и связанный, но разный и лежать должен в разных местах.

Comment: ну, мне @transaction_atomic - ни о чем не говорит, поэтому и непонятно, почему он может декорировать одну функцию. или почему его нужно выносить отдельно, а не просто дописать в декорируемую.

Comment: @UserNew "или почему его нужно выносить отдельно, а не просто дописать в декорируемую." - потому что функция в идеале должна выполнять одну конкретную задачу, все другие "неосновные" задачи лучше вынести в отдельные функции, или в декоратор в данном случае. Это способ структурирования кода и уменьшения сложности.

Answer (score 11):

В дополнение к [ответу @Sergey Gornostaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621868/10105):

Декораторы — по сути реализация аспектно-ориентированного программирования в Питоне.

Вы определяете логику или функциональность отдельно от функций, которые будут пользоваться этой функциональностью. Возможно, эту логику разрабатывает для вас другая команда. Пример с логированием, который вы видели практически везде, или те же транзакции — один из возможных примеров аспекта-функциональности. Затем вы влёгкую можете подключить использование этого аспекта без ручного переписывания функций, просто добавлением или убиранием атрибута.

В любом случае, атрибут — часть *вашего* исходного кода. Если вы хотите, чтобы недекорированная функция была доступна, вы можете просто не ставить декоратор. Или иметь отдельно недекорированную функцию, и отдельно её декорированный вариант, который вызывает недекорированный. Или дописать функциональность, которую вносил декоратор, вручную (но в этом случае вам нужно будет обновить ваш код, если в декораторе произойдут изменения, например, багфикс; это обычная проблема дубляжа кода.)

Декоратор просто позволяет вам добавлять функциональность *легко*.

Answer (score 4):

```
# во первых ссылку на функцию можно получить из декоратора
# во вторых теперь эти "куски кода в декораторе" дописать можно к любой функции, например логирование, проверка аргументов перед вызовом

def decor(fn):
    '''декоратор'''
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if all(args):
            out = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            with open('file.txt', 'a') as log:
                log.write('{} {} {} {}'.format(fn, args, kwargs, out))
            print('декоратор', end=' ')
            return out
    return wrapper

@decor
def func(*args):
    '''@декоратор(изначальная функция)'''
    return sum(args)

func(1, 2, 3)  # вызывать как декорируемую

original_fn = func.__closure__[0].cell_contents  # func без декоратора
original_fn(1, 2, 3)  # вызывать как изначальную функцию

# или
import inspect
original_fn = inspect.getclosurevars(func).nonlocals['fn']
original_fn(0, 2, 3)

# если постоянный вызов дероратора не требуется, изначальную функцию не стоит декорировать @decor
def func2(*args):
    '''изначальная функция'''
    return sum(args)

func2(1, 2, 3)  # вызывать как изначальную функцию
decor(func2)(1, 2, 3)  # вызывать как декорируемую
```

Comment: круто. Я все-таки новичок. И не видел (уже в 4-5 статьях) про декораторы никаких упоминаний, что возможность достучаться до оригинальной функции сохраняется. ) Из кода я нифига не понял, как это сделано, но результат впечатлил.

Comment: Спасибо. Особенно за доступ к оригинальной функции. И за дополнения. Жаль, что я не могу 2 ответа как ответы пометить. Или вы и тут меня удивите? Есть способ? )