# Что делает @ в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, декоратор

Во многих фреймворках и библиотеках есть что-то такое:

```
app = TeleBot(__name__)

@app.route('/command ?(.*)')
def example_command(message, cmd):
    ...
```

Или:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    ...
```

Зачем нужна @?
И могу ли я создавать свои функции с @?

Comment: Это [декораторы](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators). https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621861

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ЗАЧЕМ нужны декораторы? (НЕ как они работают, а ЗАЧЕМ)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621861/%d0%97%d0%90%d0%a7%d0%95%d0%9c-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%9d%d0%95-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%b0-%d0%97%d0%90%d0%a7%d0%95%d0%9c)